# How to expand columns and add horizontal scroll Material UI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I have too much columns it truncates the columns like this:
[image]

It looks really ugly. I don't want it to truncate. I want it to have a horizontal scroll whenever there is too much data. Also I don't want to specify a fixed column width. I want it work exactly like the Table component

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?